# Trouble getting root to build

Tags: xcode, macos

I am currently trying to learn root for my research team and getting installed on my mac. I have been following the instructions detailed at [this](http://boson.physics.sc.edu/%7Egothe/511-S15/rootlab/how-to-install-root.pdf) website and hit a snag. I've successfully installed the root package and command line tools, as well as assigned ownership of the folder to my user, however whenever I try to run

```
./configure
```

it gives the following error report:

> Checking for Xcode OSX SDK ... no
>
> configure: no Xcode OSX SDK found at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk
>
> Run xcode-select to update the developer directory path
> or make sure the desired SDK version is installed

After re-downloading Xcode and the command line tools, I've hit an impasse. The folder is obviously there, albeit seemingly as an alias ([as can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GmrF.png)) despite not being that before I started writing this and running

```
xcode-select -s '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk'
```

it only responds with:

> invalid developer directory '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs'

Anything you can tell me to get this going will be a great help.

Comment: `xcode-select` manages the active **developer directory** for Xcode and BSD tools. `xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`.

Comment: `./configure` -> ROOT is built with CMake, see https://root.cern/building-root (https://github.com/root-project/root/blob/master/configure)